# sklearn spectral clustering results in smaller number of cluster than set

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

```
from sklearn.cluster import SpectralClustering
import numpy as np
test = np.array([[63.15907836],
       [69.67386298],
       [67.20030411],
       [66.25165771],
       [62.21031327],
       [55.09531565],
       [65.85034014],
       [52.99841912],
       [52.04523986],
       [52.09008007],
       [94.65364516]])
clustering = SpectralClustering(n_clusters = 4).fit(test)
clustering.labels_
```

The upper code results in `array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1], dtype=int32)` which got me astonished. Spectral clustering requires to set a  number of clusters, which I did, but get only two clusters. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, depending on the initialization, spectral clustering (and k-means) can find empty clusters.

For instance, setting `random_state` to 17 leads to 4 clusters:

```
clustering = SpectralClustering(n_clusters = 4, random_state=17).fit(test)
```

You can find an illustration of it in for k-means (spectral clustering rely on k-means): http://user.ceng.metu.edu.tr/~tcan/ceng465_f1314/Schedule/KMeansEmpty.html